# How do I use shared view script paths for partials in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, partials, view-helpers

I'm using Zend Framework 2 (v2.1.4) and I have a partials template that I want to use in several Modules. According to [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper) I can access partials in other Modules, but

> That said, it’s likely a better practice to put re-usable partials in shared view script paths.

This sounds like a good idea, but I can't find any documentation on this "share view script path". Where do I find it, and when I've set it, how do I tell the `partial()` helper to use them?

Comment: By shared it means put them in a module that's always going to be available in your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'mymodule' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        'template_map' => array(
            'snippets/mypartial' => __DIR__ . '/../view/snippets/mypartial.phtml',
        ),
    ),
```

And use like that

```
<?php echo $this->partial("snippets/mypartial"); ?>
```